# Could I use Google App Engine to host a Java IRC Bot?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, irc

I have an IRC bot written entirely in Java that I've been hosting on my home computer, but my iffy internet connection has been disconnecting it a lot.  I've been wondering if I could use the Google Apps Engine to host the bot with a constant connection?  If so, what kind of changes am I going to have to make?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like it's time to get a VPS …

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot do that.  Google App Engine does not allow arbitrary outgoing `Socket` connections (probably because they do not want people using their platform as a proxy server).  The closest thing they offer is the [URL Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) for accessing external content over the network/Internet.

Using that, you might be able to come up with something that drives an existing web-based IRC client using an App Engine app.  Though I'm not sure what benefit that would have over just using a web-based IRC client directly.

Also you cannot have a "constant connection" to (or from) an App Engine app.  The platform will automatically time-out/close any request that has not completed processing within about 30 seconds or so.